# "Do it right, against customer's wishes" - how is it called?

Tags: design, specifications

We know the optimal situation of negotiating corrections of specifications with the customer, getting the specs to do what the client wanted, not what they said or thought they wanted. That's negotiating, explaining.

Sometimes, we're unable to convince the client. We're forced to produce broken as designed. This, called "demonology" by merit of mages summoning demons and demons fulfilling their wishes very literally, causing the mage's demise as result, is another approach that will leave the customer very dissatisfied once they realize their error, and of course try to pin the blame on the developer.

Now I just faced a very different approach: the customer created simple specs that fail to account for some critical caveat, and is completely unwilling to fix them, admit the obvious errors and accept suggested corrections. The product made to these specs will be critically broken, and possibly might cost human lives. Still, it's too late to drop the contract entirely. The contract has punitive clauses for that, ones we can't really accept.

The boss' decision? We do the work right and lie to the customer that we did it according to the specs. The algorithms in question are hidden deep enough under the surface, the product will do the work just fine, won't fail in the caveat situation, and unless someone digs too deep, they will never discover we didn't break it as requested.

Is there some common name for this tactics of execution of specs?

Comment: Failure to take into account critical scenarios in which lives are endangered is not really a matter for a contract, it's conspiracy to murder. *Your* company has strong enough morals to do what's right regardless of what the client wants, but will the next one? I think doing it right in this case may involve some sort of whistleblowing.

Comment: Common sense? Having a conscience? Sounds a bit far-fetched, to be honest. Escalation to a higher level (be that the client's boss, or their investors, or, if all else fails, the courts) should have been the way to go. Refusal to put lives at risk is never wrong.

Comment: This is called "Engineering".  When you go to get licensed as a Professional Engineer you have to take an ethics exam, and it deals with situations like this.  An Engineer has a responsibility both to protect the public safety, and to act in a professional manner towards their clients.

Comment: @Phoshi: Not really. It's an optional safety equipment that would simply fail to warn in certain situations. It's not commonly installed but in this situation it would cause a false sense of security. In this case the customer is a government organization and there is really no point trying to escalate this (only more politicians above) - the only result would be losing all future contracts.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but more people should take a software ethics class so they can see what happens when people don't think of software safety. You are morally bound not to release something you know could kill someone. Just because only politicians are above doesn't mean your company shouldn't escalate it. You want to be absolved from responsibility if this thing hurts someone.

Comment: @Rig: Thing is: by NOT releasing it we don't just lose money. We fail to deliver a much-needed safety system leaving people insecure. By doing as our boss says, we act unlawfully but everyone is happy. People are safe because the system works right. The customers don't ever need to suffer damage to their overblown egos. We're getting paid in full. Yes, we're at risk that if someone tries to dredge up dirt on us they might discover formal requirements aren't satisfied - but then, that's unlikely. Thanks to tactics like these we don't make many enemies.

Comment: ...also, we are fairly sure even if it does fail for some reason *that* flaw won't be the vector of failure if we fix it.

Comment: One thing more: that's a fairly small market. If the customers ever learn our company is willing to sue any of them, we can pack up.

Comment: May I ask, why does the client not want to do this? They're a business person surely and so can't exactly be aiming to get lawsuits..

Comment: @jozefg: No, they are government employees. My guess is simple unwillingness to admit to own errors. Matter of ego and admission to mistake before superiors: better dead than proven wrong. This is not atypical. A body of the same level, but different locality, asked to point out which of two dates (like, november 15th and december 10th) in two (equally important) documents specifying final deadline of some contract is the correct one answered "There is no difference in dates between these documents."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "name that thing" question. "Name that thing" are bad questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game

Comment: @gnat: Excellent.  I'll have to put that in my pro-forma comments script.

Comment: Honestly, talk to a lawyer here. There's obviously liability to consider.

Comment: @SF. What value is a safety system if it isn't reliable. The cost of liability in a suit against you for a death will far outweigh the loss of the contract.

Comment: @Rig: So, unless we just build it reliable, we're in a lose-lose situation. We can't not build it (deadline is final), and we can't build it to specs (flawed). The choice is quite smart: make it flawless and then if someone protests, let them argue that no, they demand flaws to be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Is the requirement(s) in question a flawed, missing or derived requirement? It matters. If the requirement is missing or can be derived from another requirement then it is a simple matter to say it is a derived requirement and you are meeting the terms of the contract. And there is no reason to hide it.

If the requirement contradicts a requirement then how are you going to validate the system without a change in requirements? The most likely reason for the government to not want to change requirements is "you will charge them more". If you are already going to implement with no extra cost then there is little reason for them to object.

Finally, because this is a government job, there will be a paper trail for all these types of decisions, if you want one. If those government employees responsible for your project won't agree verbally to the requirements change then you can formally file a requirements variance. I'm sure any variance request using terms such as "endangering life" will have ZERO possibility of being rejected. In any event, there is no reason to "hide" that you aren't meeting requirements as that could actually result in punitive damages to your company, even though you are trying to do the right thing. In this case, the right thing is to formally escalate the issue and make sure your company is protected. It is not to hide what your are doing from the customer because that is also wrong, although not as wrong as delivering a known safety hazard.

Comment: Let me emphasize: This is NOT the USA. And these government organizations may not be technical experts but are great at politics. Seriously, if you point out two different dates and ask which one is right, they *can* reply with a straight face these are both the same date and your request is invalid. Argue with that.

Comment: Ah, not the USA. In that case, maybe the government's intent is to create a safety hazard as they have nefarious plans in mind. Thus, by your not adhering to the contract then you are delivering something of no value to them. I hope nobody comes barging through your door some night once they've discovered what you've done behind their backs.

Answer (score 3):

**I am not a lawyer.  You should neither act nor refrain from acting on any opinions I provide.**

Releasing a product that could put lives at risk due to a design flaw (rather than as a necessary part of its operation) that you are aware of is likely to put you the wrong side of health and safety legislation as well as expose your organisation to legal claims and costs.  In most territories and situations the law of the land overrules any contract you may have so that should be your priority.

In other words:  Clarify your specific legal position before continuing.

Comment: It isn't so much "put lives at risk" as "fail to prevent...". The customer always has an option of not moving a finger and leaving people to depend on their own hunch as they were for centuries past. The device would not cause deaths, it would just fail to prevent ones it was meant to prevent.

Comment: SF an analogy would be a seat belt - it doesn't "cause deaths" by itself.  However if it fails and the person dies as a result - you can bet the maker is liable and will be sued!  The fact that seat belts didn't used to exist on cars doesn't help make a case.

Comment: @SF: If your company is aware of the design flaw, then the company can be held liable. In my company our legal department would never let us sign a contract, which would put the company at risk. If your or your boss lied to your legal department, good luck.

Comment: @Simon: This is a small company with no legal department. The market requires us to take contracts before full extent of works is known - make too many requests and someone else will swipe the job from before our noses. This time the caveat was discovered rather late. The difference with seatbelts is that they are currently mandated by law. Think more like parachutes installed in passenger seats of airliners.

Comment: @SF. Seatbelts were not always mandatory.  A safety system must work if it's installed.  If it fails then the designer/maker is at fault and will be held liable in court.  If the cause is found to be a design defect that was known then you can expect the court to show you no mercy.  A good lawyer will be able to explain better using appropriate examples.

Comment: @JamesSnell: Thing is, we face a choice between: [No safety system, angry customer, no contract money, clear legal standing] and [Fully working system, satisfied customer, fully paid contract, somewhat dubious legal standing]. Of course "demonology" (building the system following wrong specs) would be a very bad solution here (faulty system, dissatisfied customer, struggle for money from contract, dubious legal standing) but we don't intend to use demonology here.

Comment: I highly suggest to get some professional legal advice.

Comment: @SF. You do face more choices than the two you've outlined - a good outcome can be achieved without lying to the client and without risking imprisonment.  But you will need support from a professional legal expert to make it happen in a way which allows you to deliver on the contract and get paid without also breaking the law.

Comment: @JamesSnell: In this particular case, likely the lawyer costs would exceed the expected profits long before resolution. Especially that a device that doesn't perform to specs can be "fixed within warranty" (only costs of modifying the algorithms). That's the worst that can really happen to us currently. Also, I have a strong suspicion the customer understands the SNAFU but is unwilling to admit mistake and silently hopes we do what we're about to do. That way their reputation is never at stake and the device performs just fine. It's not just about law, it's very much politics.

Comment: (in particular, the contract is pretty clear on punitive charges for delays in delivery. We're better off deploying an empty box that does nothing, and "fixing it" as warranty repairs by filling it with electronics as they are developed, than to delay deployment for *any* reasons.)

Comment: @SF Look. You don't try to save money by talking to us instead of a lawyer, and then ignore our advice when it's (inevitably) "Talk to a lawyer and not us."